# I get teleported when executing a command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I really have no clue what isn't working here. I have these lines of code:

```
execute as @a[scores={skillTry=1..}] rotated ~ 0 run tp @s ^ ^ ^3

execute as @a[scores={skillTry=1..}] run scoreboard players set @s skillTry 0
```

So what's happening is when I right click (Turns skillTry to 1) it literally just teleports me to 8,-62,11. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need to change is where the command is executed, currently, it executes as the player but at the command block.

Change to this:

```
execute as @a[scores={skillTry=1..}] at @s rotated ...
```

Just added the `at` word to make the command execute at the player, wich is needed for the tp command to teleport relative to the player and not the command block.